# Not operator in regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, not-operator

Given the following string

```
1080s: 33, 6&apos;2&quot; meg: test. 1748s: I THINK IM GONNA <span class="highlight" >PICK</span> 1749s: TWO COMPLETE OPPOSITES.
```

I want to do regex operation on it, and want the following matches

```
1st match : 1080s: 33, 6&apos;2&quot; meg: test. 
2nd match : 1748s: I THINK IM GONNA <span class="highlight" >PICK</span> 
3rd match : 1749s: TWO COMPLETE OPPOSITES.
```

I am using the following regular expression in ASP.NET to perform the match

```
MatchCollection mcs = Regex.Matches(txtData, "(\\d*)(s:)([^(\\d*)](s:){0})*");
```

The regex will match, but the captures are incorrect. The regex skips the text as soon as it find `\d*` or `s:`. I want it to skip if and only if `\d*s:` is found together.

I tried it a few different ways but still haven't found how to combine both `\d*` and `s:` in a not operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regex positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as suggested by @Ilya,

```
var pattern = @"\b(?=\s*\d{0,4}s:)";
var lines = new Regex(pattern).Split(input).Where(
    s => 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()) == false).ToArray();
```

**Explanation**
`\b(?=\s*\d{0,4}s:)` -> Starting with a word boundary, Match a suffix but exclude it from capture. The suffix is defined as 'Any number of whitespace characters followed by digit of length 0 to 4, followed by s, and then followed by `:`. 

Once the input has been split, then clean the input to remove empty entries.

Comment: Thanks Devendra.. it work pretty good.. just have one issue. my numeric word before s: can be of 0 to 4 char long.. it may not always 4 char. long...
i have applied below changes on it... 
@"(?=\s*\d{1,4}s:)" and  @"(?=\s*\d*s:)" 

but it do not return me exact result as i need.. can u help me out in this?

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell the regex engine: "In the end of the regex, right after the match, there must be a `(\\d*)(s:)` or an end-of-string". This can be done using a **lookahead**.

Comment: thansk llya... i really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match any number of digits (not just exactly 4) you can do it using this code:

```
var pattern = @".+?(?<!\d)((?=\d+s:)|$)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

The `.+?` is a **non-greedy** match of at least one character. It has to be non-greedy, otherwise the `.+` will match the entire string skipping past any occurrences of `\d+s:`.

The `(?<!\d)` is a **negative lookbehind** that ensures that the last character matched by `.` isn't a digit. This is required because the number of digits isn't fixed to say 4. If this lookbehind isn't included the input 'X12' can match as either `any, digit, digit` or `any, any, digit`. You want to avoid the second match and need the lookbehind to ensure that `1` is matched as `digit` and not `any`.

The `((?=\d+s:)|$)` is a **positive lookahead** that ensures that the match ends with either some digits followed by `s:` or is simply the end of the string (`$`). Note that this lookahead is an assertion and it isn't included in the match. It just ensures that the match is followed by the lookahead.